# Listing DirectoryEntry children: why so slow?

Tags: vb.net, performance, directoryservices

Or rather: what can I do about it?

My objective is to list all accessible network devices in a home network using .NET. Preferably without digging into the WIN32 API, and without resorting to a series of funky WMI queries.

The following code does exactly that:

```
    Imports System.DirectoryServices

    (...)

    Dim network As New DirectoryEntry()

    network.Path = "WinNT:"

    For Each workgroup As DirectoryEntry In network.Children()

        For Each computer As DirectoryEntry In workgroup.Children

            If computer.SchemaClassName = "Computer" Then
                Console.WriteLine(computer.Name)
            End If

        Next

    Next
```

However, if you run this code you will experience an incredibly noticeable delay when accessing the `Children` getter on the DirectoryEntry instances. Even though my network only has one workgroup with three connected devices. I can imagine that the problem becomes much worse on larger subnets.

So again, why is this the case and what can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried [**`DirectorySearcher`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) instead?

Comment: Yes, but I was under the impression that it requires extra setup somewhere because the `FindAll()` call threw a `NotSupportedException`. Maybe I just don't know how to use it properly...

Comment: You may have to research more and experiment with different matching patterns to get it working, but it will be much faster.  In my experience it can be very touchy on what is allowed for search criteria and how it's allowed to be specified.

Comment: Can I use a `DirectorySearcher` without any prior installation? I don't know all that much about Active Directory (never needed it before), and if it requires a specific setup then I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for. My target is home networks without fancy AD server boxes.

Comment: Gotcha, ya I don't know if it is only supported by AD.  I just remember getting weird error messages because I didn't form my queries right, but it's more likely that home network just doesn't support the DirectorySearcher at all.  Sorry.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input anyway.

So far, my code seems to be the only managed way to achieve my goal. There might be something in the WMI toolset that does the same thing, but I feel really bad everytime I touch it. The only other option I could find is calling native methods in netapi32.dll, but P/Invokes are a black art that I prefer to avoid at all costs.